# CSS doesn't work with xhtml2pdf Django

Tags: html, css, django, xhtml2pdf

I'm trying to improve my generated PDF created by `xhtml2pdf` with some `CSS style` in my `Django Project`.

I would like for example to `justify a text block`, but apparently, it doesn't work and I don't find why. I'm reading lots of documentations about this library, I wrote some CSS scripts but still nothing.

**This is my HTML file :**

```
<html>
    <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style>
            p {text-align: justify;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <font face="Courier New, monospace"

    <body>
        <logo class="logo">
        <img src='/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Etat_civil/Etat_civil/static/images/logo.png' />
        </logo>
        <h2 align="center"> <font color="red" size="6"> ACTE DE NAISSANCE <br /> COPIE INTEGRALE </font></align> </h2>

        <br></br>
        <br></br>

        {% block content %} 

        <h3 align="left"> ACTE DE NAISSANCE N° {{birthcertificate.id}} / {% now "Y" %} {{birthcertificate.firstname}} {{birthcertificate.lastname}}</align> </h3>

        <br></br>

        <p>Le {{birthcertificate.birthday}} est né, {{birthcertificate.firstname}} {{birthcertificate.lastname}}, du sexe {{birthcertificate.sex}}, <br />
        de {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.firstname}} {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.lastname}}, né à {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.birthcity}} ({{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.country}}) le {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.birthday}}, {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.job}},<br />
        et de {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.firstname}} {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.lastname}}, née à {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.birthcity}} ({{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.country}})<br />
        le {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.birthday}}, {{birthcertificate.fk_parent2.job}}, domiciliés au {{birthcertificate.fk_parent1.adress}}.
        </p>
        <br></br>

            Dressé le {% now "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" %} à ... , lecture faite et invité à lire l'acte, a signé avec Nous, <br /> {{user}}, chevalier de la Légion d'honneur, officier de l'Etat Civil.


        <h3> Le {% now "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" %}
        <br /> Par la présente, l'Officier d'Etat Civil certifie la conformité de la présente déclaration </h3>

        <br></br>

        <h3 align ="right"> L'Officier d'Etat Civil </align> </h3>
        <h3 align ="right"> Signature et tampon </align> </h3>

        {% endblock %}

        </font>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I generate the PDF, I get this file :

[image]

As you can see, the block text is not justified. I also tried to add a `background-color` but always the same problem, it doesn't take account.

Thank you so much if you have an idea !

**EDIT :**

I found the answer : sentences were not enough long to justify the text !

Comment: try providing id to each element you are giving css styling like instead of <p> make it <p id='first_p'> and then do the styling

Comment: what do you mean with your *EDIT* comment? can you explain more, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not have the CSS attribute "text-align: justify" in xhtml2pdf.
Following attributes are integrated:

```
background-color
border-bottom-color, border-bottom-style, border-bottom-width
border-left-color, border-left-style, border-left-width
border-right-color, border-right-style, border-right-width
border-top-color, border-top-style, border-top-width
colordisplay
font-family, font-size, font-style, font-weight
height
line-height, list-style-type
margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top
padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right, padding-top
page-break-after, page-break-before
size
text-align, text-decoration, text-indent
vertical-align
white-space
width
zoom
```

The updated link for [documentation](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/docs/source/reference.rst)