# CSS is not working after converting of HTML to PDF in Django

Tags: html, css, django, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to convert an HTML file to PDF for download purpose in Django using xhtml2pdf library. But after converting to PDF, the CSS is not working.
Here is my HTML code snippet:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Certificate</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link href="{% static 'koss/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

.test {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -309px;
    left: 331px;
    color: #151313;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#profile_image1{
    margin-top: -147px;
    margin-left: 171px;
}

#profile_image2{
    margin-left: 156px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="test">
<h3>name 1</h3>
    </div>

     <div class="test">
<h3> name2  </h3>
    </div>

     <div class="test">
<h3>name3  </h3>
    </div>

  <img id="profile_image1" alt="image" class="img-fluid  m-3" src="{% static  'koss/img/memcirti1.png'%}"
                            onerror="imgError(this);">
     <br>

      <img id="profile_image2" alt="image" class="img-fluid  m-3" src="{% static  'koss/img/memcirti2.jpg'%}"
                            onerror="imgError(this);">

</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please have a look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308254/xhtml2pdf-not-applying-css-while-creating-pdf-html-to-pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS doesn't work with xhtml2pdf Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461975/css-doesnt-work-with-xhtml2pdf-django)

Comment: here i wrote  styles in the head of the HTML template only but why its still not working?